# Logic App (Consumption) Handling Lost Locks (not Timeout)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We have instances where our service bus message lock has been lost before it can be completed.  MS referred me to the documentation:

> Important
>
> It is important to note that the lock that PeekLock acquires on the
> message is volatile and may be lost in the following conditions
>
> Service Update OS update Changing properties on the entity (Queue,
> Topic, Subscription) while holding the lock. When the lock is lost,
> Azure Service Bus will generate a MessageLockLostException which will
> be surfaced on the client application code. In this case, the client's
> default retry logic should automatically kick in and retry the
> operation.

We already handle the 5 minute timeout with a parallel loop.  Now we need to handle a lost lock due to volatility.  What is everyone's best practice here?

- A resubmit is not appropriate - in case of duplication
- Dead-lettering cannot be done because the lock is lost, a second instance will already have started for the same message
- Message could be completed immediately, however we lose the dead-letter ability etc...

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a good solution for you?

- Change the logic app to be http triggered
- Add another logic app triggered by the message that creates a record in a storage of some sort with the state of processing the message set to 0 for example and then calls the first logic app
- Add another logic app that sets the record to complete state 1 for example
- When the logic app finishes, it calls the second logic app to update the record

What happens:

- message arrives
- new logicapp1 picks it and completes the message
- new logicapp1 creates a record and calls your main logic app
- main logic app do its processing
- main logic app calls new logicapp2
- new logicapp2 updates the record as completed

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was hoping for something more "out of the box".  During further reading yesterday we came across deferring messages and that seems like it could be a good solution in this scenario.  There is also the max delivery count that I could play with i.e. set it to one, therefore only one receiver.  I need to poc both, but also need the client buy in so need to be confident.